# Match all numeric characters without letters before or after

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I try this:

```
\d+(?![a-zA-Z]+[0-9])\d+
```

but for this string:

```
azeaze4 T4 45-azej565 5T 555T 44444
```

I want to find:

```
45 44444
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `\d+` within a word boundary :

```
\b\d+\b
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/kH4cV5/1

Comment: I've never seen `\b` before. +1 much better than my answer

Comment: new problem => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851300/match-all-numeric-characters-without-letters-or-accented-letters-before-or-after

Answer (score 0):

This will find the write characters for you

```
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])\d+(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```