# Match all numeric characters without letters or accented letters before or after

Tags: java, regex

I try this:

```
\b\d+\b
```

but for this string:

```
0225 : appt, (parking) niv -2 0015_1 5étage sqdqs25485 7871sdd
```

I want to find:

```
0225 2 0015 1
```

Comment: what language you use?

Comment: I change the post, i tag JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<![\p{M}\p{L}\d])\d+(?![\p{M}\p{L}\d])
```

You can achieve it this way.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/24

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
(?<![\p{L}\d])(\d+)(?![\p{L}\d])
```

where:

- `(?<![\p{L}])` - negative lookbehind for single code point in the
  category "letter",
- `(\d+)` - one or more digits,
- `(?![\p{L}])` - negative lookahead for single code point in the
  category "letter",

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gI5pZ0/2)

Comment: I change my string test input

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to obtain the required numbers:

```
String s = "0225 : appt, (parking) niv -2 0015_1 5étage";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=_|\\b)\\d+(?=\\b|_)", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/IVMSBz)

The regex means match 1 or more digits (`\d+`) only if they are preceded with `_` or a word boundary (`(?<=_|\\b)`) and followed by a word boundary or an underscore (`(?=\\b|_)`).

Use `(?U)` flag (or `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`), since `\b` without `(?U)` flag is broken.

Comment: Whoever wants to downvote, please leave your comment before or right after. Better do it before, since there is no sense in playing downvote-delete-repost game.

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need mote assistance?